# Traer datos de mysqlite y setear un editext android con java

Tags: android-sqlite, edittext

Hola quería consultar sobre:

Como rellenar edittext desde una base de datos mysqlite, ya que me rellena los 2 primeros editext (campo nombre y campo apellido) pero los otros no.

Y me da un error de tipo “Invalid ID 0x000001cb” por ejemplo.

No se si está mal el código o esta fallando la base de datos el emulador o que puede ser.

Sepan disculpar si es muy burdo mi posteo, es la primera ves que uso el foro y también soy novato en programación.
Muchas gracias de antemano por sus respuestas :).

El código que use es el siguiente:

public class vista_actualizar_eliminar_clientes extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btn_editar, btn_borrar,btn_volver,btn_buscar;
EditText campoid,camponombre, campoApellido, campoDni, campoMatricula, campoEmail,campoDireccion,campoTelefono;
ConexionSQLiteHelper conn;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vista_actualizar_eliminar_clientes);

    conn=new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),"db_clientes",null,1);

    btn_editar = findViewById(R.id.btn_cargar_cliente);
    btn_borrar = findViewById(R.id.btn_borrar_cliente);
    btn_volver = findViewById(R.id.bnt_volver_de_editar_cliente);
    btn_buscar=findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar_cliente_por_id);

    campoid=findViewById(R.id.txt_id_edit);
    camponombre=findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_edit);
    campoApellido=findViewById(R.id.txt_apellido_edit);
    campoDni=findViewById(R.id.txt_dni_edit);
    campoMatricula=findViewById(R.id.txt_matricula_edit);
    campoEmail=findViewById(R.id.txt_mail_edit);
    campoDireccion=findViewById(R.id.txt_direccion_edit);
    campoTelefono=findViewById(R.id.txt_telefono_edit);




}



public void onclick_vista_actualizar_cliente(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_cargar_cliente:
            editar();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_borrar_cliente:
            borrarCliente();
            break;

        case R.id.bnt_volver_de_editar_cliente:
            Intent volver=new Intent(vista_actualizar_eliminar_clientes.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(volver);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_buscar_cliente_por_id:
            consultar();//ver error no trae todos los parametros buscados y dice que el "id" no existe
            break;
    }
}

private void editar() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
   
    String[] parametros ={campoid.getText().toString()};

    
    ContentValues nuevavalues =new ContentValues();


    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,camponombre.getText().toString());
    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_APELLIDO,campoApellido.getText().toString());
    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_DNI,campoDni.getText().toString());
    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_MATRICULA,campoMatricula.getText().toString());
    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_EMAIL,campoEmail.getText().toString());
    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_DIRECCION,campoDireccion.getText().toString());
    nuevavalues.put(Utilidades.CAMPO_TELEFONO,campoTelefono.getText().toString());


  
    db.update(Utilidades.TABLA_CLIENTES,nuevavalues,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+ "=?",parametros);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se actualizaron los datos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();



}

private void borrarCliente() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] parametros ={campoid.getText().toString()};
    db.delete(Utilidades.TABLA_CLIENTES,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"=?",parametros);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se eliminaron los datos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();

}
private void consultar() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] parametros ={campoid.getText().toString()};

    String[] campos={Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_APELLIDO,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_DNI,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_MATRICULA,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_EMAIL,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_DIRECCION,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_TELEFONO};
    try {
        Cursor cursor=db.query(Utilidades.TABLA_CLIENTES,campos,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"=?",parametros,null,null,null );
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        camponombre.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        campoApellido.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        campoDni.setText(cursor.getInt(2));
        campoMatricula.setText(cursor.getInt(3));
        campoEmail.setText(cursor.getString(4));
        campoDireccion.setText(cursor.getString(5));
        campoTelefono.setText(cursor.getInt(6));
        cursor.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El documento no existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"El problema se debe a que usas un valor de tipo entero directamente en tu TextView usando setText(), lo que cree tu aplicación es que tratas de cargar un recurso que se encuentra en la app pero este no existe, para resolver este problema en el caso de los valores enteros usa String.valueOf(...) para convertir el valor Int a String:"

copio la respuesta que me dio @Jorgesys en otra pregunta que realicé, gracias a el resolví el problema.